# php foreach not showing first value in array

Tags: php, loops, foreach, echo, associative-array

I have an array `($vEvents)` as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1174
        [date] => 120411
        [name] => DR. J 'Souled Out' ~ 9pm (No Cover)
        [pubId] => 44
        [price] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1108
        [date] => 120410
        [name] => Verb presents Open Stage ~ 9pm (No Cover)
        [pubId] => 44
        [price] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1104
        [date] => 120409
        [name] => DR. J 'Souled Out' ~ 9pm (No Cover)
        [pubId] => 44
        [price] => 
    )
[currLimit] => 10
[eventsRemaining] => 4
```

I am echoing it to the screen with:

```
reset ($vEvents);
foreach ($vEvents as $key => &$value) {
    if ($key != 'currLimit' && $key != 'eventsRemaining'){ //Makes sure it doesn't print out the limiter value
    $m = substr($value['date'],0,2);
    $d = substr($value['date'],2,2);
    $y = '20'.substr($value['date'],4,2);
    echo date("D", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y)).", ".date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y))." ".$d.", ".$y." - ".$value['name'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

But on my output, instead of getting all displayed array entries, it keeps skipping the first one... Output:

```
Sat, Dec 04, 2010 - Verb presents Open Stage ~ 9pm (No Cover)
Fri, Dec 04, 2009 - DR. J 'Souled Out' ~ 9pm (No Cover)
```

However, my expected output should be:

```
Sun, Dec 04, 2011 - DR. J 'Souled Out' ~ 9pm (No Cover)
Sat, Dec 04, 2010 - Verb presents Open Stage ~ 9pm (No Cover)
Fri, Dec 04, 2009 - DR. J 'Souled Out' ~ 9pm (No Cover)
```

I have tried changing the values in the `name` key and such, but all other entire show fine, it just always skips the first key.  I have never had this issue before.  Thoughts?

When I comment out the:`if ($key != 'currLimit' && $key != 'eventsRemaining'){ //Makes sure it doesn't print out the limiter value` line, it works fine.  Is it relevant that the key of the first element is zero?  But why would that fail my `if` check?

Comment: Your code looks alright. Is there anything happening between your print_r() and your loop? By the way, you can spare the `reset`-call as it should not have any effect.

Comment: The code and array contents you posted dont properly represent the code and array contents youre actually executing. run the code and array you posted in a brand new totally separate script, and you'll see it works.

Comment: try to debug value inside the for loop

Comment: @yankee I added the `reset` to try and debug the issue.  usually I wouldn't have added it.

Comment: @chris there is one line I was using in there, but I don't see how it would affect it...  Please see update question

Comment: Not saying it's definitely the problem, but would you mind sharing why you're prefixing your loop variable with the ampersand?

Comment: Are your numerical keys actually numerical or are they strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is weird when it deals with values of 0... it treats them as false in most cases.  So,

```
if ($key != 'currLimit' && $key != 'eventsRemaining')
```

is going to evaluate to false when $key == 0.  I would change it to:

```
if ($key !== 'currLimit' && $key !== 'eventsRemaining')
```

Comment: Perfect!!!  While I know 0 equates to false in php, I had no idea that would come into effect with this type of syntax.  Using the strict comparison worked great, thanks!!!

Comment: Did a little digging and found out that because $key is an integer value, PHP converts 'currLimit' to an integer... which evaluates to 0.  So 0 != 0 is false.

Comment: thanks again!  This is why I love SO.  Users like you who not only provide excellent answers, but also a clear explanation as to why.  That is how we all learn :)

Answer (score -3):

Because this is an array, I would try using a different type of loop that should give you the expected results:

```
<?php

$length = count( $vEvents );

for( $i = 0; $i < $length; i ++ )
{

$key = $i;
$value = $vEvents[ $i ];

//rest of the loop code here

}
?>
```

Comment: my understanding is the foreach loop is specifically used for iterating through an array, starting at the first element, and ending at the last

Comment: foreach is an abstraction not specifically for arrays, but well suited for arrays. It is perfectly fine to use foreach as I perceive it as an addition to code readability.

Comment: foreach is best when you do not know the keys/indexes of an object, while for loops are better for indexed arrays.

Comment: @SteveBinder: That isn;t true since you can use foreach for associative arrays as well like this: `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`

Comment: the question here however is why is the foreach skipping the "0" index, that is why I recommended a for loop.

Comment: the problem is there are two keys that I will need to access later in the loop after I troubleshoot this issue.  They are associative.  Thus why I am trying to use a foreach.